# C++ conversion from vector<pair<double*,pair<double*,int*>> to array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My problem is, even though I use operator[] to get my vector contents, the vector is 
calling always the size function (according to my profiling tool and time measurements).
So since my C++ application is very time critical (less than 0.1ms), i thought I'd better convert it into an array, but I couldn't figure out so far.
The actual vector looks like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double*,std::pair<double*,int*>>>
```

Comment: Please post some supporting code to get a clear picture of the situation.

Comment: are you sure you are working with a release build? (The debug build might check bounds, the release shouldn't). Which STL implementation are you working with?

Comment: I know it is because of the Debug build, but I have to work with it.

Comment: why would you have to work with Debug build if it's a time critical application??

Comment: You have to work in debug mode **and** your application is time critical? This sounds sub-optimal, to say the least.

Comment: I have no idea why. It's not my decision

Comment: It really sounds like an April fool's day joke. By trying to meet some nonsensical requirements, you will end up writing bad code. I  guess whoever made that decision will have to live with that.

Comment: You should feel responsible for what you're doing. If you need to create bad code because of someoneelse's decisions, try to talk. Try to find out what's behind the decision. Maybe they require Debug symbols for profiling? This can be added to Release builds without performance penalties. And so on...

Comment: I definetly see your points and with all your suggestions ( besides using the release build) I already meet the requirements. I could already squeeze some more miliseconds out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to a pointer to the first element of an array like this:

```
pair<double *, pair<double *, int *> > *ar = &v[0];
```

Use `v.data()` instead of `&v[0]` in C++11.

Unrelatedly, I'm a little bit sceptical that the `size()` function is taking up a measureable amount of time.  It's usually an inline function that either returns a field or returns the difference of two pointer fields.

Comment: I'm not working with C++11, because my employer demands to use the visual studio 2005

Answer (score 6):

As the question is tagged with 'visual-c++', I will assume this compiler is being used.

The Microsoft implementation of the C++ standard library includes various checks to detect situations that produce undefined behaviour and produce a runtime error instead. These checks are enabled by default (even for release builds!), but you can disable them by defining `_SECURE_SCL` as `0`. See [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](https://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/ahazelden/entry/visual_studio_stl/) for more information.

Comment: now it's better but still vector::size gets called too much. I actually already take care of the Size value